# How to code a function that checks if an array contains a number by returning a boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, boolean

I just started learning code and i'm currently stuck on the following assignment.

Assignment:

Code a function that checks if an array contains a number by returning a boolean.(Java code)

Examples: contains([1, 2, 3, 4], 3) returns true. contains([2, 2, 4], 3) returns false.

I've tried the following:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxLig.png)

Can anyone help me with solving this one?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to add your code into code blocks on editor and do not upload images containing code. Also you state that you started learning code, but you do not specify the language. Your code is javascript code, you should specify it and tag it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate for each array element. Considering that your array contains numbers check the following function

```
function contains(numberArray, check){
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
    if (numberArray[i] == check){
      return true;
    }
  }
    return false;
}
```

It takes the numberArray array as input and the check number. Then it iterates for each number in the array and checks if it finds the same number with the check number.

If it finds it, then it returns true and the loop breaks.

If it does not find it, after the loop is finished iterating all the elements of the array, then it returns false.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

You can use the includes() method which is available for JavaScript arrays. It will check if a specific element is included in the array and will return a boolean value of either true or false.

```
function contains(array, number){
    var ans = array.includes(number);
    return ans;
}

console.log(contains([1,2,3,4],3)); // Prints true
console.log(contains([2,2,4],3));   // Prints false
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: @EduardoBaitello Thanks for informing me. Hope it's a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

An [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) is a collection of elements of a specific type. Your function takes two parameters: the array in which you want to search, and the number you want to search.

To achieve this, you have to iterate through the array, using a controlled iteration like a [for loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop). The loop takes all elements in the array one by one, and performs an action that you define in the loop body, in your case you can compare the current array element to the one passed to your function. If they are the same, you can return from the loop using the `return` statement. If all elements were

Assuming that you're using JavaScript, you'd do something like this using the [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```js
function contains(array, number){
    for(var currentElementIndex in array) {
        if(array[currentElementIndex] === number) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```